# Adding records via curl and JSON in Airtable via curl

Tags: json, macos, curl, photoshop, airtable

I'm having a problem making a new record in Airtable via curl (I don't have any problems getting records).

Following the Airtable example to create a record only works if I exactly copy and paste it.

```
$ curl -v -XPOST https://api.airtable.com/v0/appSA9wfOqZoOkjQY/Table%201 \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "fields": {
    "Name": "Y78585-BKMU",
    "Notes": "Y"
  }
}'
```

If I copy and paste it in the terminal that code will work. If I copy and paste it into a text editor, and then paste that into the terminal it will work, but if I edit anything it fails with the following error.

```
{"error":{"type":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"Could not parse request body"}}
```

The only thing I changed was the value in quotes in the name field. Really stumped with this. :^/  Any help appreciated, it must be simple.

Comment: Welp, I guess there was some weird return or space in there somewhere because tinkering around finally solved the issue.